# Ruby on Rails pull an id from url, insert into image_tag (gsub?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, gsub, twitpic

I have a twitter feed displaying my tweets on a page. I want to include the thumbnails of my twitpic images as well. I've been using gsub to replace text, but I'm having a hard time figuring out the syntax.

A typical 'twitpic tweet' output with a raw tag will look like this:

```
This is a tweet with an image. http://twitpic.com/12345
```

Then the link for the image is

```
http://twitpic.com/show/thumb/12345.jpg
```

Here's the simple code to display the text:

```
<% @tweets.each do |tweet| %>
  <li>
    <%= raw tweet.text %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

So I've been experimenting with gsub but am pretty stuck.

I can search for http://twitpic.com/* by /http:\/\/twitpic.com?[^]+ and then take out everything with the url, replacing it with raw html, but this doesn't help if I want to link an image.

If I could extract the twitpic id (http://twitpic.com/12345), I could put that 12345 into a helper method that inputs a string and inserts it into a linked image.

If anyone could give me some insight on how to extract this id, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use #split instead of a regex?

```
"This is a tweet with an image. http://twitpic.com/12345".split("http://twitpic.com/")[1]
```

Comment: Maybe not the most elegant solution, but this worked wonderfully:<%= raw tweet.text.gsub(/http:\/\/twitpic.com?[^>]+/) { link_to image_tag("http://twitpic.com/show/thumb/#{tweet.text.split("http://twitpic.com/")[1]}", :border=>0), "http://twitpic.com/#{tweet.text.split("http://twitpic.com/")[1]}" } %>

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract id from `http://twitpic.com/show/thumb/12345.jpg` then try this to fetch the id out of it:

```
"http://twitpic.com/show/thumb/12345.jpg".scan(/^http:\/\/twitpic.com\/show\/thumb\/(\d+).jpg$/).flatten.first
```